# avnant checkout failed randomly

Tags: svn, ant, svnant, svn-checkout

I'm using ant to do fresh checkout of latest version of application in repository.
Using command like:

```
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <checkout url="${url.to.my.repo}/trunk" destpath="${path.to.dir}"/>
    </svn>
```

Quite often I get following error:

```
  [svn] svn: CRLF expected at end of chunk: XX/YY
  [svn] svn: REPORT request failed on '/myApp/!svn/vcc/default'
  [svn] svn: CRLF expected at end of chunk: XX/YY
  [svn] svn: REPORT request failed on '/myApp/!svn/vcc/default'
  [svn] <Checkout> failed.
```

`XX` and `YY` are "randomly" defined.

After some retries checkout is successful.

This error occurs like a little bit more than 2 minutes.

Using Windows 7 with svnant 1.3.1.

Any ideas?

10x